# Calculate the day tomorrow and if it is Sunday show two more days - Mysql

Tags: mysql, date, case

I'm trying to make a query where one of the fields shows the units of the orders table that are planned tomorrow, but if tomorrow is Sunday it should be Monday.

I have the table orders and the table format.

Orders table:
id_order, order_date, units

Format table:
id_format, format_type

My query initially is this:

```
SELECT format_type, units, DATE (NOW () + INTERVAL 1 DAY) as Tomorrow
FROM orders Join format on orders.id_format = format.id_format
WHERE DATE (date_delivery) = DATE (NOW () + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

But it would have to be something similar like this:

```
SELECT format_type, units, DATE (NOW () + INTERVAL 1 DAY) as Tomorrow
FROM orders Join format on orders.id_format = format.id_format
WHERE (
  CASE
  WHEN DAYNAME (date) = "Sunday" THEN DATE (order_date) = DATE (NOW () + INTERVAL 2 DAY)
  ELSE DATE (order_date) = DATE (NOW () + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  END;
```

_____EDIT_____

This is the result I wanted

```
SELECT format.format_type, units, DATE(NOW()) as TODAY
FROM orders Join format on orders.id_format = format.id_formatopeso
WHERE
  CASE
    WHEN WEEKDAY(now()) = 6 then DATE(order_date) = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY)
    ELSE DATE(order_date) = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuu can simply select what you have in where

```
  SELECT format_type, units, 
      CASE
        WHEN  WEEKDAY(date) = 6 
            then DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL +2  DAY)
            else DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL +1  DAY)
        END as tomorrow_with_sunday_check, 
      DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL +1  DAY) as Tomorrow
  FROM orders Join format on orders.id_format = format.id_format
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it does not work, the query that I put was improvised, I get this error:
ERROR 1630 (42000): FUNCTION databasemyname.NOW does not exi
st. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Ma
nual

Comment: Edit, Now this my query working perfectly, Thanks for you help scaisEdge

Comment: Hi, your answer is accepted, this not is exactly I wanted, but this help me.

I can vote, because I don't have votes, if I have put other way you tell me.
Thanks